# Infinite loop issue on array deps in hook

Tags: reactjs

How can i stop the infinite loop issue of the component. So i have Parent and a child component

**Parent.js**

```
const { revertBack, onRevertChange, defaultData } = props


const [data, setData] = useState(initializeData(defaultData))


const onChange = useCallback(
    (id, value) => {
        const upcomingData = { ...data };
        upcomingData[id] = value;
        setData(upcomingData);
        if (revertBack) onRevertChange(upcomingData);
    },
    [onRevertChange],
);
```

**Child.js**

```
const {enabled, activated, onChange, id  } = props

useEffect(() => {
   if (enabled && activated) {
        dateRef.current.focus();
      } else {
            onChange(id, '');
      }
    }, [enabled, activated, onChange, id]);
```

Here on the **Parent.js** from the array deps if i remove the data, it works fine. But the lint warnings shows its a dependency.

I am little newbie to this hooks, any help is appreciated

Comment: Does it work if you remove `onChange` from dependencies array?

Comment: @radovix are you referring to onRevertChange? if yes then yes, even i pass empty array as deps it works, then only eslint shown these warnings that its empty array you need to pass data and onRevertChange as array deps

Comment: I was refering to the `useEffect` in the `Child.js`.

Comment: yep  its working so what i tested is, child.js [enabled, activated, id] and parent.js [] - this what you were asking isn't @radovix

Comment: Not sure if we understood each other right haha. I just wanted you to remove the `onChange` from `useEffect` in the `Child.js` and leave `Parent.js` as it is in the question.Let me know if that works.

Comment: child.js [enabled, activated, id] and parent.js [onRevertChange] - yep no infinite loop issue but eslint warnings are there in both files

Comment: Copy-paste the warning for me please.

Comment: Child.js -> warning  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'onChange'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. If 'onChange' changes too often, find the parent component that defines it and wrap that definition in useCallback

/***********/

Parent.js ->  warning  React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'data'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

Comment: @radovix I have added the warnings

Comment: @radovix Here the problem is data, if i add it in arrays deps as per eslint it will be infinite, without adding it will work but esline warning remains

Comment: Not sure how to fix those. Eslint never really gave me any of those warning :/

Comment: I am also searching, few approaches i tried by passing [Object.values(data)], but still same warning

Comment: @radovix happy to share the info, added the answer. And many thanks for responding :)

Comment: Hope I helped at least a little :D